# Google Sheets- query cells that contain multiple lines of text

Tags: google-sheets

I was trying to write a simple query when I came across something that didn't make sense to me. I was struggling with writing a query to return cells corresponding to a descriptive cell that had a double asterisk in it: '**'. Here is a simplified version of what I was attempting:

```
=QUERY(F:G, "SELECT F WHERE G IS NOT NULL AND G LIKE '%**%'")
```

The query was returning an empty output, which confused me, because it shouldn't have; everything I have learned about QUERY suggested that this should work flawlessly. After about 30 minutes of troubleshooting I finally found the issue. The cells in which I had the asterisks were cells that I inserted multiple lines for a description (e.g. I would write a line, press ctrl+enter, then use ** to flag what I needed to flag). If I place everything on a single line, it works as intended.

The weird thing to me, is that QUERY will return multi-line cells as long as LIKE is not involved. Which sucks for me, because I would really prefer to keep those cells the way they are for readability reasons.

My main question is: why are multi-line cells a limitation of LIKE. My secondary question is: Is there a way to use QUERY to return the cells I want with the multi-lines, OR is there a function or combination of functions that will allow me to do the same. I have used INDEX and MATCH before, but not in this way so I'm not sure how to adapt; I think REGEX might be a possible way forward, but I am terrible with it, just can't wrap my head around it for some reason.

EDIT: Here is a link to a sample sheet to demonstrate: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1lq6Xu7hrLjJgTgc8B4pe36RND6QcKWAco377ZqxJhcU/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: here is the link to the sample sheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1lq6Xu7hrLjJgTgc8B4pe36RND6QcKWAco377ZqxJhcU/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one approach:

```
=QUERY(Data!A2:B, "SELECT B WHERE B IS NOT NULL AND B CONTAINS '**'")
```

OR

```
=let(Σ,Data!B:B,
    filter(Σ,Σ<>"",regexmatch(Σ,"\*\*")))
```

---

```
=QUERY(Data!A2:B, "SELECT B WHERE B IS NOT NULL AND lower(B) contains 'world'")
```

[image]